# Livewire button won't click

Tags: laravel-livewire

I'm trying to make a button to a function. When I click the button, it won't display the output
Here is my button view

`<button wire:click="edit({{ $data->id }})" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>`

Here is my function

`public function edit($id){ dd('$id');}`

and here is my layout

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @yield('page')
            @yield('update')
        </div>
    
    <script>var HOST_URL = "https://keenthemes.com/metronic/tools/preview";</script>
    <script>var KTAppSettings = { "breakpoints": { "sm": 576, "md": 768, "lg": 992, "xl": 1200, "xxl": 1200 }, "colors": { "theme": { "base": { "white": "#ffffff", "primary": "#8950FC", "secondary": "#E5EAEE", "success": "#1BC5BD", "info": "#8950FC", "warning": "#FFA800", "danger": "#F64E60", "light": "#F3F6F9", "dark": "#212121" }, "light": { "white": "#ffffff", "primary": "#E1E9FF", "secondary": "#ECF0F3", "success": "#C9F7F5", "info": "#EEE5FF", "warning": "#FFF4DE", "danger": "#FFE2E5", "light": "#F3F6F9", "dark": "#D6D6E0" }, "inverse": { "white": "#ffffff", "primary": "#ffffff", "secondary": "#212121", "success": "#ffffff", "info": "#ffffff", "warning": "#ffffff", "danger": "#ffffff", "light": "#464E5F", "dark": "#ffffff" } }, "gray": { "gray-100": "#F3F6F9", "gray-200": "#ECF0F3", "gray-300": "#E5EAEE", "gray-400": "#D6D6E0", "gray-500": "#B5B5C3", "gray-600": "#80808F", "gray-700": "#464E5F", "gray-800": "#1B283F", "gray-900": "#212121" } }, "font-family": "Poppins" };</script>
    <script src="dist/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js?v=7.0.4"></script>
    <script src="dist/assets/plugins/custom/prismjs/prismjs.bundle.js?v=7.0.4"></script>
    <script src="dist/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js?v=7.0.4"></script>
    <script src="dist/assets/plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js?v=7.0.4"></script>
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBTGnKT7dt597vo9QgeQ7BFhvSRP4eiMSM?v=7.0.4"></script>
    <script src="dist/assets/plugins/custom/gmaps/gmaps.js?v=7.0.4"></script>
    <script src="dist/assets/js/pages/widgets.js?v=7.0.4"></script>
    
    @livewireScripts
```

Comment: Do you have @livewireStyles in your layout as well?

Comment: yes. I already added the @livewireStyles

Comment: Can you add the blade where you're using the component?

Comment: I already resolve the issue

Comment: Can you answer your own question with the solution? This helps people in future that are searching for something related

Comment: I basically rework my layout and the button can access my function